# SQL Management show field with FK, which actually is not a FK

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

In my SQL Server Management Studio 2016, in the Object Explorer there is a field, part of a composite PK, in some tables like this:

- ProjectCode (PK, **FK**, varchar(255), not null)

But when I see the relationships of the table, or the database diagram, there is no real relationship with other table.

Is this an error of the Management Studio, or what does mean the **FK** and why it is appearing there?

Comment: Could you pls post a `create table` script for one of such tables?

Comment: We can't see your screen and have no idea what you are talking about.